# WebSocket PHP handles each message separately

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I use Ratchet library to create websocket on php and I set a timeout of 10 seconds to return a message to the client, then I see that it will wait for the first message to be processed before processing the next message, how to make each message it will process always without waiting for the previous message

**socket.php**

```
<?php

 namespace MyApp;

 use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
 use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {
protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    sleep(10);
    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s"' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg);
    $from->send("Server Reply: ".$time);
     
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

    $conn->close();
}
}
```

**run.php**

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Socket;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require "socket.php";
$server = IoServer::factory(
new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
        new Socket()
    )
),
8765
);

$server->run();
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPx8R.png)

Comment: PHP executes in a single thread by default; if you want several messages to be handled in parallel, you'd need to spin up several threads.

Comment: because every message always be +10 seconds, you need to test with diferent delay for each client to test concurency

Comment: for example, give client1 delay 10seconds, then give client2 delay 5seconds. lets see if client2 handled first or not.